# how to recover data from a broken mobile phone which has an inbuilt storage only

Tags: data-recovery

My Lenovo Zuk z1 came under a bus and it broken into pieces. Is there any possible way from which I can recover some data from it as it contains some memorable moments of my nephew  adding that Zuk z1 does not have a external memory?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at our [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) for a starter. You'll find some relevant questions (with answers) linked from there. As I expect the screen being broken too, also see our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) for additional hints. For good answers it would help if you could [edit] your question and add some details concerning the state of the device: How much broken is it? Literally pieces?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try Chip-off acquisition, physically removing (desoldering) the phone's flash memory chip and then use a specially tool Android Phone Datarecovery DS3000-USB3.0-emcp221.

Comment: But how do I recognize the  ROM on the circuit board? I googled for it but can't get a satisfactory result

Comment: Normally the ROM is near the Procesor, you can use the schematic

Comment: Here is the schematic http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f1000/lenovo-schematics-diagram-pcb-lay-out-available-2197590/

Comment: Would u please mail me the content of the link as it asking for a id for downloading content and not accepting any user name???? Email at...22vishal1994@gmail.com